# Algorithm for building tree hierarchy based on URL paths

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

This is related to [Parse Url Strings into Tree Hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711793/parse-url-strings-into-tree-hierarchy)

But i'm implementing in javascript, therefore require some algorithm here instead of using SQL functions.

Answer (score 2):

[Prefix tree/Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [Suffix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree#Functionality)

It is really difficult to suggest one over the other unless you specify the sort of operations you intend to perform over and above organising them.

Comment: Actually i'm interested in the implementation as well. I need to generate a JSON object based on the URL.

{
 "text":"aFolder",
 "children":[
  {
   "text":"file",
  },
  {
   "text":"file2",
  }
 ]
},
{
 "text":"bfolder",
 "children":[
  {
   "text":"file",
  },
  {
   "text":"cFolder",
   "children":[
    {
     "text":"file",
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}